# Возможно ли в Git изменить(не удалить) конкретный файл во всей истории

Tags: git

Хотелось бы почистить ненужную информацию из историю коммитов.

Comment: Используйте `git filter-branch ...`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно создать новую историю, очень похожую на текущую, но содержащую другую версию файла.

Делается это при помощи интерактивного `rebase`

Подробности можно прочитать в [git-book, глава 7.6 Инструменты Git - Исправление истории](https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v2/%D0%98%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B-Git-%D0%98%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B8)

Как только на старую историю не будет ссылаться ни одна ветка/метка, она будет автоматически удалена.

**UPD**

Для случаев, когда нужно изменить большое количество коммитов, есть вариант автоматизации rebase — `git filter-branch`. Он позволяет автоматизировать изменения не только содержимого, но и параметров коммита, таких как сообщение, автор и дата. Подробности по той же ссылке.

Comment: Спасибо, думаю это именно то, что я искал

Answer (score 0):

Я думаю вам поможет `git rebase -i`

Comment: Здесь говорят по руским языке